# Save video while streaming in VLC

Tags: vlc-media-player

I use VLC to stream YouTube videos.

1. Is there any way to also save the video to a local file at the same time as I am watching it? I mean without consuming any more megabytes off of my data plan.
2. Is there any way to save all YouTube videos by default every time I stream them with VLC?

EDIT: I am on OS X 10.10.1

EDIT: To those who are offended by the violation of YouTube's TAC implied in the question, please just pretend the question was about a stream provided under the GPL.

Comment: See 5.1 (L) of the YouTube [Terms and conditions](https://www.youtube.com/t/terms). *""Streaming" means a contemporaneous digital transmission of the material by YouTube via the Internet to a user operated Internet enabled device in such a manner that the data is intended for real-time viewing and not intended to be downloaded (either permanently or temporarily), copied, stored, or redistributed by the user."*

Comment: Come on... I would understand this sort of comment from a Google representative, but on SE? It is completely impossible to enforce a ban on downloading YouTube content, and even if this ban may exist in the TAC, it is never even attempted enforced by Google. For example, Google even allows extensions that do this in the Chrome Webstore. Allowing such extensions in the Chrome Webstore is an extreme example of Google "de facto" allowing downloading of Youtube videos.

Comment: @Burgi The world is sadly wider then UK ;-) Try to change the _Terms and Conditions_ country settings from UK to worldwide and the word _"streaming"_ will  disappear as point (L) from the whole document... I do not know if to download a file is an infringement of those terms in all other countries... (Try with NZ too there is not that point). I've checked a couple of version for different countries and these are different even inside the EU... We cannot know all the language of the world and all the country terms of youtube... maybe if the OP checks for his country we can even answer him...

Comment: @Hastur Changing the zone to [worldwide](https://www.youtube.com/t/terms?gl=US) the clause I mentioned disappears but 5 (B) says _"You shall not download any Content unless you see a “download” or similar link displayed by YouTube on the Service for that Content."_

Comment: @Burgi So there are cases for which it is possible...and always when you have the written consent of the licensor ( _"...without the prior written consent of YouTube __or the respective licensors__ of the Content"_), always if this is not in contrast with local laws (more o less restrictive) that we don't know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Read the help of Vlc <sup>[[1](http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch06.html)]</sup>, it is an interesting lecture of a might program.
2. In general if you know the real source of a stream or a file you can **download it & watch meanwhile**, maybe with `wget http://where/it/is/mystream.mp4` and run vlc over the *downloading* chunk.

   ```
   wget http://where/it/is/mystream.mp4  &  
   vlc mystream.mp4
   ```

   If in your country is allowed or you have the right to do it, you can use VLC to clean the link to the file and to download it, without loss of quality <sup>[[2](http://lifehacker.com/the-best-hidden-features-of-vlc-1654434241)]</sup>

   > - In VLC, head to Media > Open Network Stream.
   > - Paste the stream link in the box and click Play.
   > - Under Tools, click Codec Information.
   > - In the box that says Location, right-click the block of text and click Select All. Copy this text to your clipboard.
   > - Go back to your browser and paste the link in the address bar. This will open the source file directly on YouTube's servers.
   > - Right-click the video as it plays and select Save Video As
   >     or download it with `wget`
3. You can also **record clips** from VLC  by pressing the red Record button in the player itself; this is a conversion with all that it concerns.
4. When you write the link in the *open network stream* there is the possibility to **p**lay <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, to **s**tream <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> or to c**o**nvert <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>. Chosing the streaming (*stream to a file*) or conversion case meanwhile you can see it too. Probably if you choose the same encoding for video, audio you can have a not lossy output. The shortcut from keyboard can be different for language different from English or in different version of Vlc.

Comment: I was frustrated with VLC streaming, but not saving to file and I came across this one. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

In VLC

1. go to -> File -> Open Network...
2. Paste Youtube URL
3. check Stream/Save, click Settings
4. enter a file path, or browse...
5. Check show stream locally if you want to watch while downloading